# Cannot import defined variables from Dart file to an another

Tags: dart

I have defined the int c in a dart file called (main.dart)
I want to use this variable in another Dart file called (ex.dart). The both dart files are in the same directory (bin)
I used this code (import 'main.dart';) also this (import './main.dart';) . But it gives me this Error: Getter not found: 'c'.
it could not define c , although it was previously defined in (main.dart) file.
any one can help ?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. What you describe should work. It's impossible to guess what you are doing differently without seeing the actual code.

Comment: The variables are defined in a right way and could be printed but they cannot be imported !

Comment: The variable is defined globally right? Not in the main function?

Comment: Might this error linked to depencies in .yaml file ?!!!!

Comment: It's unlikely to be dependency related. If your compiler doesn't scream at you about a missing import file, then it probably found `main.dart`. Again, you need to show us the actual code that doesn't work, we can't guess what's wrong from your description, because the description sounds correct.

Comment: Okay Irn i am just new to this site tell me how to send the code?

Comment: @KarimRefaay Edit your question and copy and paste your code (ideally a minimal version of it that reproduces your problem).

Comment: Thanks all a lot , I had a wrong which is having two Void main (){} in each file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.